# CNN1D learns only one class in a binary classification problem (Keras)

Tags: tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

I try to find in a graph the nodes which belong to a particular structure (for example a clique). I must therefore have at the output a vector `[0,0,1,0,1,1,0 .......]` where the 1 represents the nodes belonging to the cliques.

My inputs are graphs where each node of the graph is represented by an embedding vector, the input is in this form:

```
[[-1.548624, 2.6481668, 0.21574, -0.324527 ........]
[.....] ...[.....]].
```

the problem is that my model only learns one of the two classes, either (1) or (0) depending on the greater presence in the dataset. after doing a data rebalancing the results are around 0.5 accuracies.

I tried the data rebalancing, change of embedding method but the result remains the same.

Does anyone have any idea what is causing the problem?
here is the code:

```
def model(input_shape):
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Conv1D(30,3,input_shape=input_shape,activation="sigmoid"))
    model.add(MaxPool1D(9))
    model.add(LSTM(50,return_sequences=True))
    model.add(Flatten())
    model.add(Dense(889,activation="sigmoid"))
    #model.summary()
    opt = tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(learning_rate=0.01)
    model.compile(loss='mse',optimizer='sgd',metrics=['binary_accuracy'])
    return model

train_x,train_y,test_x,test_y,val_x,val_y = load_data()
model=model((889,64))
model.fit(train_x,train_y,validation_data=(val_x,val_y),epochs=500,batch_size=4)
```

I am not sure of my (activation function, loss, metric) even if the best results given are with this.

```
120/120 [==============================] - 4s 13ms/step - loss: 0.7967 - binary_accuracy: 0.3721 - val_loss: 0.4342 - val_binary_accuracy: 0.3979
Epoch 2/8
120/120 [==============================] - 1s 8ms/step - loss: 0.3795 - binary_accuracy: 0.4164 - val_loss: 0.2758 - val_binary_accuracy: 0.4871
Epoch 3/8
120/120 [==============================] - 1s 8ms/step - loss: 0.2594 - binary_accuracy: 0.5262 - val_loss: 0.2304 - val_binary_accuracy: 0.6379
Epoch 4/8
120/120 [==============================] - 1s 8ms/step - loss: 0.2255 - binary_accuracy: 0.6643 - val_loss: 0.2181 - val_binary_accuracy: 0.6910
Epoch 5/8
120/120 [==============================] - 1s 8ms/step - loss: 0.2161 - binary_accuracy: 0.6914 - val_loss: 0.2148 - val_binary_accuracy: 0.6921
Epoch 6/8
120/120 [==============================] - 1s 8ms/step - loss: 0.2136 - binary_accuracy: 0.6922 - val_loss: 0.2139 - val_binary_accuracy: 0.6921
Epoch 7/8
120/120 [==============================] - 1s 8ms/step - loss: 0.2132 - binary_accuracy: 0.6917 - val_loss: 0.2137 - val_binary_accuracy: 0.6921
Epoch 8/8
120/120 [==============================] - 1s 8ms/step - loss: 0.2129 - binary_accuracy: 0.6919 - val_loss: 0.2136 - val_binary_accuracy: 0.6921
5/5 [==============================] - 0s 11ms/step - loss: 0.2137 - binary_accuracy: 0.6915
[0.21371755003929138, 0.6915410757064819]
```

thank you in advance for your feedback;).

Answer (score 0):

First of all, 1D convs are a lot different from 2D convs. For 2D convs you want to keep the kernel size low because the number of calculations scales as the square of the kernel size C*K^2 (for 3d convs it gets cubed!), but for 1D it scales linearly. You really want to up that kernel size.

Secondly, you need to normalize your inputs for certain ML approaches, neural networks being one of them.

Finally, I'm a bit worried CNN is the wrong approach for this anyway. On top of that you have a LSTM, which I don't really follow. Maybe start of with just a couple dense layers as a good baseline.

One debugging tip, make a really small dataset and make sure you can overfit i.e. memorize the training set.

Comment: What do you think would be the right approach for this?

Comment: @DEvop60 I'd say make a basic block of dense, relu, batchnorm, and start with 1 or 2 blocks and add more as needed.